# java.lang.RuntimeException: Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.14.1

Tags: android, build.gradle, jcenter

When i try to upload my model library to jcenter, run `gradle install`
 ,here is full prompt message

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/huanjulu/Documents/PermissionHandler/PermisisonHandler/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Here is my `gradle-wrapper.properties` :

```
#DATE
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Here is my project `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my app build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "huanjulu.runtimepermission.com"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':permissionhandler')
}
```

And sure i am using default gradle wrapper in Open File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `gradle install`, you don't use the gradle wrapper but the locally installed gradle version.

Do instead:

```
gradlew install
```

or on Linux

```
./gradlew install
```

Comment: glad to hear. You may want to accept the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

you need to download the last version from https://gradle.org/releases after that go to file/project structure/project and put the new version in gradle version

Answer (score 0):

Change:

1. In your `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
   ```

   with

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
   ```
2. In your `project` level `build.gradle`:

   ```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
   ```

   with

   ```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
   ```
3. In your `project` level `build.gradle`:

   add `google()` under **both** `repositories{}` blocks